# Its virtual box legal?

Tags: virtualbox

I had this question

I install virtualbox in order to learn about this program, and i found that had the oportunity to run windows, even windows 3.1 to windows 8, my corcern is about the copyright, one of the reasons why, currently im an ubuntu user is because is opensource, and im against breaking the law (i dont like that microsoft has privative code, but i respect his desicion)

The official site says that is opensource, but, how this can be opensource and at the same time offer windows? (windows allow this company to offer his program?)

Comment: Virtualbox doesn't *offer* windows, it just allows you to run it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have experience with Virtualbox, but if it is like the other virtualization programs I have used, when it comes to installing any version of Windows it may offer to download an .iso of it for installing. However, you will need a **valid activation code** in order to continue using it beyond the default activation time period.

For other non-opensource or EOL'd OS's (re: Windows XP and earlier), you will probably need to have an installer disc and activation/license code to install and use them.

Comment: Also note that you will need an own licence for each virtual Windows installation you use.